# add single quote to an array : Here is my code

Tags: php, arrays, implode

```
$sql= 'select * from `name` where `author_id` IN (' . implode("','", $authors_ids) . ')';
```

Where `$authors_ids` is an array.

Comment: id is a number, you don't need quotes.

Comment: concat single quote at start and end of implode

Answer (score 2):

This could be the answer.

```
$sql = "select * from `name` where `author_id` IN ('" . implode("','", $authors_ids) . "')";
```

But as mentioned by other people in the comments why transform it to a string instead of just having it as an integer? (I am assuming the id is an integer).

```
$sql = 'select * from `name` where `author_id` IN (' . implode(",", $authors_ids) . ')';
```

NB. I am also here assuming you have done some security around your authors array before it is passed to this.

Comment: no it's giving error and author id is string

Comment: What error? it is very hard to help you without more information

Comment: server giving 500 error which means there are some error in syntax..

Comment: It works - https://3v4l.org/ieSMh

Answer (score 0):

You are adding single quotes to elements.

But, we need to add it to end and start manually.

```
$authorsStr = "'" . implode ( "', '", $authors_ids ) . "'";
$sql= 'select * from `name` where `author_id` IN (' .$authorsStr . ')';
```

Say, you have array of authors:

`$authors = ['Bob', 'Willy', 'Williams'];`

In your case, sql:

```
select * from `name` where `author_id` IN (Bob','Willy','Williams)
```

Which is definitely, a syntax error.

If you add single quotes to start and end manually as above, your sql will become:

```
select * from `name` where `author_id` IN ('Bob','Willy','Williams')
```

Which does not contain any syntax error.

Comment: Your code is giving 500 error

Comment: Please read the answer carefully. I am sure it will fix your issue.

Comment: here is my code $sql_correspondence = 'select * from authors where author_id IN (' . implode("','", $authors_ids) . ')'; 

here is output :

select * from authors where author_id IN (Dalia3128','Ahmed8683)